# Replacing a character in a elements of string list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I have a list in which some strings end with a certain character .Now I need to remove this character from  these strings.

say : `['abc-','xyz','jkl-']`

result should be `['abc','xyz','jkl']`

What I am trying is:

```
>>>List.append([s.replace('- ',' ')[:-1] for s in List ])
```

But it removes the last character from other strings as well .

Comment: `s.rstrip("-")` prehaps?  And when you `.append` it to list you are not replacing the elements in the original list, you would have to do `List[:] = [s.rstrip("-") for s in List]` to override the content of the list.

Comment: Why are you replacing with a space?

Comment: What should happen with `['abc--']`: do you expect `['abc']` or `['abc-']`? I.e. is the last character special, or do you want to strip potentially multiple trailing characters?

Comment: l = map(lambda x: x.rstrip('-'), l)

Comment: Pardon my noobness, and thankyou all, s.rstrip('-') does the trick .And yes Padraic I would have wanted  to omit all the trailing characters and s.rstrip('-') omits that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match to `replace` with `'- '`, your character followed by a whitespace character. There are no whitespaces in your strings, hence replace does nothing and then you just slice all of your strings' last character off. Furthermore, there is no point in adding a space and then slicing it off, and your current method wouldn't account for your character elsewhere in your string, for instance `two-putt`.

Just remove the slice and use [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove the trailing character you don't want.

```
>>> l=['abc-','xyz','jkl-']
>>> l[:]= [x.rstrip('-') for x in orig]
['abc', 'xyz', 'jkl']
```

You can use a list comprehension to create a new list then just overwrite your original's contents. Note that with this method, if your strings end with several of the character you don't want, they will all be removed, for example. `'dogs---'` will become `'dogs'`. If you want to handle trailing whitespace as well, you can supplement a space along with the character you do not want to `rstrip`, with `.rstrip('- ')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension which considers every item in your list and for each item, takes all but the last character if the last character is a dash:

```
>>> List = ['abc-', 'xyz', 'jlk-']
>>> [x[:-1] if x.endswith('-') else x for x in List]
['abc', 'xyz', 'jlk']
```